# Setting EditText's minLines

Tags: android, layout

I have a simple layout:

[image]

and I want to make the `EditTexts`(the Views below) the same height as `TextViews` above. I want to avoid hardcoding height. For the `TextViews` I did `android:minLines = 2`. Unfortunately, this does not work for `EditTexts`. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the height?

I am aware that this can be easily done if the `EditText` is to the side of the `TextView` in a `wrap_content` `LinearLayout` and then setting the `layout_height` of `EditText` to `match_parent` but, my views are in a vertical layout.

EDIT: Here is the layout of one of those columns

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/item_spacing"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_spacing"
        android:text="@string/xdim" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/xdim"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the styles:

```
<style name="TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/back</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
<style name="EditText" parent="@style/TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/item_border</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can try to have both of the above inside a LinearLayout. Then use android:layout_weight="0.5" and android:layout_height="0dp" for those two. Did you try something like this?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: Don't move attributes with `layout_` to styles - http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/11/keeping-styles-in-scope